# Поменять местами строки и столбцы в матрице

Tags: матрицы, c++

Дана матрица, в которой надо поменять строки и столбцы местами. Ниже код, который уже набросал, но он не меняет местами строки и столбцы.
Кто может объяснить, как правильно в с++ можно поменять строки и столбцы? Спасибо.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

const int n = 4;

int R[n][n] = {
        { 4, 8, 11, 5, },
        { 2, 12, 9, 14 },
        { 0, 5, 0, 7 },
        { 1, 6, 3, 4 }
};

void main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    cout << "Исходная матрица: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cout << R[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    //Меняем местами строки
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int tmp;
        //Ниже ошибки
        tmp = R[0, i];
        R[0, i] = R[3, i];
        R[3, i] = tmp;
    }

    //
    cout << "Преобразованная матрица: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cout << R[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В код особо не вчитывался, но должно быть так:

```
tmp = R[0][i];  
R[0][i] = R[3][i];  
R[3][i] = tmp;
```

Comment: Ой, точно, спасибо, @nuts119. Допустил глупейшую ошибку.